# Function to return data set partly based on global variable

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I want to make a function which does the following:
Take in a data set
Check global variable x if it is 0 or 1
If x is 0 then it should turn x to 1 and return the data set without the first line
If x is 1 then it should leave x and return every line.

The data set is

`mid counts
1  -2.25      3
2  -1.75      6
3  -1.25     14
4  -0.75     14
5  -0.25     17
6   0.25     19
7   0.75     12
8   1.25      9
9   1.75      4
10  2.25      2
11  2.25     -3
12  2.75     -6
13  3.25    -14
14  3.75    -14
15  4.25    -17
16  4.75    -19
17  5.25    -12
18  5.75     -9
19  6.25     -4
20  6.75     -2`

Function I have now

`testfunc = function(set){
    print(x)
    for(i in 1:nrow(set)){
           ifelse(x == 0, x <<- 1, return(set[i]))
    }
}`

This gives as result the print of x and only the counts row of the data set without the first line left out.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, `x` does not depend on `i` so there is no need for a loop, it will  always return if `x == 0` and `i == 1`. And in that case the return value will be `set[-1, ]`.

Comment: basically I need to know why
`ifelse(x == 0, x <<- 1, return(set[i]))`
doesn't drop the first line when `x == 0` but gives the whole set and why the return is only the second column of the set.

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your function was a bit wrong.

First of all, you don't need the `for` loop *at all*.

Second, you don't need the `ifelse` to test just one value. `length(x) == 1` so you will be testing the one value of `x` and this should be done with a plain `if`.

And look to what this `ifelse` is doing:

```
ifelse(x == 0, x <<- 1, return(set[i]))
```

This reads *"if `x` is zero, set `x` to 1 in the `GlobalEnv` else return `set[i]`"*. It is clearly not what you want.

A correct way could be the following.

```
testfunc <- function(set){
  print(x)
  if(x == 0){
    x <<- 1
    return(set[-1, ])
  }else{
    return(set)
  }
}
```

Now test it, first with `x == 0`.

```
x <- 0
res <- testfunc(dat)
x
#[1] 1

head(res)
#    mid counts
#2 -1.75      6
#3 -1.25     14
#4 -0.75     14
#5 -0.25     17
#6  0.25     19
#7  0.75     12
```

The value of `x` in the global environment has changed and the returned dataframe does not have the first row.

Now `x == 1`.

```
res <- testfunc(dat)
x
#[1] 1

head(res)
#    mid counts
#1 -2.25      3
#2 -1.75      6
#3 -1.25     14
#4 -0.75     14
#5 -0.25     17
#6  0.25     19
```

The value of `x` did not change and the returned df is the original one.